# Recording Audio in background on Android 8

Tags: android, audio, alarmmanager

As you know on new operating systems background services have some limitations and also the Doze Mode has been introduced. My aim is to record audio when app is in background at certain time and for a certain period of time. So I have two questions:

A) If I have a rooted phone and my app acquires the root permissions. Can I run a background service continously like older version of android without the system killing it and then record as much as I want?

B) In case I have a not root phone: I have tried the AlarmManager aproach, using different variants but the results are very unpredictable. First of all I tried to check which is the maximum amount of time that allows me to record before process is killed:

AlarmCreated Class:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    AlarmManager alarm2 = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2 , intent2, 0);
    alarm2.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + (1*1000) , pendingIntent2);
```

AlarmReceiver Class:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    alarm = (AlarmManager) con.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1 , intent, 0);
    alarm.setAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis() + ((2*60*1000) + 10000), pendingIntent);

    AsyncAudio bg = new AsyncAudio(context);
    bg.execute();
 }
```

AsyncAudio Class:

```
public class AsynkAudio extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener{

   @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
       startRecording();
       return null;
    }

   @Override
   public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {

       if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
           stopRecording(true);  
       }
   }

   private void startRecording() {
     mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
     mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
     mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
     mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
     mRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(64000);
     mRecorder.setOnInfoListener(this);
     mRecorder.setMaxDuration(2*60*1000);
     mRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(16000);
     mOutputFile = getOutputFile();
     mOutputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
     mRecorder.setOutputFile(mOutputFile.getAbsolutePath());
    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mRecorder.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }

  private File getOutputFile() {
      SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat
            ("yyyyMMdd_HHmmssSSS", Locale.ITALY);
      return new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
            + "/Voice Recorder/RECORDING_"
            + dateFormat.format(new Date())
            + ".m4a");
  }

   protected void stopRecording(boolean saveFile) {
      mRecorder.stop();
      mRecorder.release();
      mRecorder = null;
   }
 }
```

What I get is audio with different time durations. From 6 seconds to 2 minutes as expected.

So What would be the best aproach to achive my goal? Without a rooted phone?

Comment: Oh.. So root permission pratically prevent the system to kill my app. This is intresting.. For what concern not rooted phone and  AlarmManager. Do you think there is a possible way to understand when the process is killed and then schedule the alarm just a moment before?

Comment: Oh thanks for the root tips. Anyway, the problem with stickyService I think is the same.. I can be killed any time.. explecially if the phone is in Doze Mode. I was using that before AlarmManager.

Or your suggestion is something like.. AlarmManager is set, when Broadcast is received I spawn a Servince (the eventually call asynctask) and not, like I m doing right now, once the broadcast is received directly call asynctask. Am I right?

Comment: Foreground service is what I wanto to avoid.. I will try the service option